# Search for a value in JSON using php

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON file in this format:

```
[
 ["name","purpose","description"],
 ["name2","purpose2","description2"],
 ["name3","purpose3","description3"]
]
```

Now, I have got the solutions for finding them by key. But, my JSON doesn't have keys. How can I search inside this JSON object to find second element by using "purpose2"? Also, I need to display the second element (i.e. "name2","purpose2","description2").

I used this function, but it's not helping me out.

```
function searchJson($obj, $value) {
foreach($obj as $item) {
    foreach($item as $child) {
        if(isset($child) && $child == $value) {
            return $child;
        }
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried to decode it? `$arr = json_decode($json, true); var_dump($arr[1])`

Comment: Yes I did  decode the JSON first.

Comment: So, you can use your PHP object, this is just an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the json data doesn't have string keys upon which to search you can branch the logic in the function to test for numeric indexes and then use `in_array` perhaps

```
$json = '[["name","purpose","description"],["name2","purpose2","description2"],["name3","purpose3","description3"]]';

function searchJson( $obj, $value ) {
    foreach( $obj as $key => $item ) {
        if( !is_nan( intval( $key ) ) && is_array( $item ) ){
            if( in_array( $value, $item ) ) return $item;
        } else {
            foreach( $item as $child ) {
                if(isset($child) && $child == $value) {
                    return $child;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
$data = json_decode( $json );
$results = searchJson( $data , 'purpose2' );
print_r( $results );
```