# PHP: How to search for an ID in a tree-like JSON structure recursively and return the path including all previous IDs

Tags: php, json, path

I have a specific problem that I can't handle.
I have a JSON file and I need to find the id in it.
I need to get all previous id when id is found.

Find id 51.
Results: 51, 12962, 1101, 1100

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
{
"status":"SUCCESS",
"data":[
    {
        "id":"12522",
        "name":"name 1",
    },
    {
        "id":"13081",
        "name":"name 2",
    },
    {
        "id":"1100",
        "name":"name 3",
        "childs":[
            {
                "id":"11591",
                "name":"name 4",
                "childs":[
                    {
                        "id":"12382",
                        "name":"name 5",
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"48",
                        "name":"name 6",
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"11590",
                        "name":"name 7",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id":"1101",
                "name":"name 8",
                "childs":[
                    {
                        "id":"11589",
                        "name":"name 9",
                    },
                    {
                        "id":"12962",
                        "name":"name 10",
                        "childs":[
                            {
                                "id":"51",
                                "name":"name 11",
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

....

Comment: please provide the JSON as a string, not a screenshot!

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far in PHP, and what specific problem(s) did you encounter?

Comment: I'm sorry, I added JSON instead of the picture.

Comment: Did you try to resolve your issue? Or you just want other people to resolve issue for you?
In first case, please provide PHP code, so we can check what is going wrong.

Comment: I used the code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011865/search-for-a-value-in-json-using-php
Please ask for the full php code if possible.
I'm starting to program for JSON, so I apologize for my question if it's a problem.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've stripped down the JSON input for this example, but the result is an array holding the IDs up until the id you're looking for (or empty if the id hasn't been found). The code is annotated so you can see what it actually does. Basically, I'm using a recursive function, meaning a function that calls itself, passing on the current stack of ids on each call.

```php
<?php
$data = json_decode( '[{"id": "1234"},{"id": "4567"},{"id": "1100","childs": [{"id": "7890"},{"id": "1101","childs": [{"id": "12962","childs": [{"id": "51"}]}]}]}]' );

// recursively go through the data, searching for the id
function findIdRecursive( $id, $data, $stack = array() ) {
    foreach ( $data as $d ) {
        // this object corresponds to the id
        if ( $d->id === $id ) {
            $stack[] = $id;
            break;
        } else if ( isset( $d->childs ) ) {
            // recursively go through this object's children
            $childStack = findIdRecursive( $id, $d->childs, $stack );
            if( in_array( $id, $childStack ) ) {
                // if the id is present in the child stack, return this path
                $stack = array_merge( [ $d->id ], $childStack );
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $stack;
}

// [ 51, 12962, 1101, 1100 ]
var_dump( array_reverse( findIdRecursive( "51", $data ) ) );
```

Comment: Thank you for your sample.
Unfortunately, I have a problem with that.
Notice: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object array (0) {}
if ($ d-> id === $ id) {

Comment: That happens when you execute my code without change? That would be rather odd, because it sounds like one of the objects doesn't have an `id` property? Or are you calling the function on the response instead of the `response->data`?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the code.
I would like to upload a json file for testing.
Is it possible, please?

Comment: Well, if you copied and executed my code exactly as it is, I'm a bit lost as to why it would work for me but throw a Notice for you.

Comment: I performed a test for a valid JSON here https://jsonlint.com/
JSON is valid.

Comment: Yeah of course the JSON is valid, as the example code is running perfectly fine for me... ;) or are you saying that the error occurs when running my function on your data? In that case, that would have been valuable information... And if it is indeed the case, can you please also answer my question above, whether you're running it on your result object or its data property?

Comment: Yes, there is an error running your code on my data.

Comment: 1) You're forcing to parse objects as associative arrays instead of objects, using the second parameter of `json_parse(..., true)`. But the function is built to work with objects. So either leave out that second parameter, or, if you really need to work with associative array instead, change all instances of `$d->id` to `$d['id']` and `$d->childs` to `$d['childs']`. 2) As I already said, you have to pass the `data` to the function, not the whole results object. Compare the dummy data in my example code: It doesn't have a `status` property, but corresponds to `$data_json->data`!

Comment: I understand.
I changed it to var_dump (array_reverse (findIdRecursive ("51", $ data_json-> data))); and now everything is working.
Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that!